# How do I make a Selenium test for a page with a textbox whose name constantly changes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to create a test that can enter a username and password into a login form on a page. However, the textbox name changes on every load of the page, and so the test stops each time I run it.

How can I set up Selenium IDE so that it can identify the text box across refreshes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//form[1](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html) (3) - First form element in the HTML

Pulled from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html) as an example This is making use of [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). In theory you can make use of [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to focus on parsing the structure of the XHTML, however this is fairly fragile, so it's not necessarily a wise thing to do but it should take care of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that the textbox only changes part of the ID and not the entire ID each time.

To work with this I would recommend using xpath like people have put above but make it more robust in that it only find that element each time.

e.g.

`//input[contains(@id,'thePartOfTheIdThatNeverChanges')]`

or

`//input[starts-with(@id,'thePartOfTheIdThatNeverChanges')]`

or

`//input[ends-with(@id,'thePartOfTheIdThatNeverChanges')]`

Answer (score 1):

Does the location of the text box change, or just the name?

You could use a css or xpath selector to get the text box if it is in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend CSS because - 
a. for the readability
b. for the ease of access (and, in your case, maintainability).

I use firebug for accessing/formulating the CSS identifier.